# .NET MAUI 7: How to set font for some 'special' elements? Or set a global font? (for dialogues, calendar, flyout tabbar, context menu button)

Tags: maui, maui-android

in our .NET MAUI 7 Android App, we've added a custom font and attach it to all possible elements. However, there are some elements for which we have not yet found a way to change the font:

Dialogues

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oNqN.png)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF5s7.png)

Calendar

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Exet.png)

Flyout Bottom Tabbar

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge6NB.png)

Context Menu Button

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsEQ7.png)

How can we define the font for these elements? And, is there a way to define a global font for Android and iOS, which also affects those elements (and could then be overwritten for other elements?

Thank you so much!

David

Comment: Some controls have FontFamily property, all you have to do is style them. Some have to be customized manually. Search for Renderers in Xamarin / Handlers in MAUI.

Comment: David, to be sure I understand, are you saying that if you define a `Style` (in App.xaml) for those elements, there is no way to specify `FontFamily` in the Style?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve as far as I found out, those elements cannot be styled with the regular code in the App.xaml - but instead, Handlers have to be used. Still figuring out how that works though :-(

Comment: I find that you posted it on Q&A. You can refer to the [comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1285140/net-maui-7-how-to-set-font-for-some-special-elemen). The content is good.